# \Coloneqq symbol to use it with mtpro2 fonts version lite

Tags: macros, symbols, packages, mtpro, amssymb

We know that into the `txfonts` package exists a specific symbol `::=` called `\Coloneqq` that it produces this output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
$f(x)\Coloneqq \alpha^{\beta}_{\gamma}$
\end{document}
```

This symbol does not even exist with `mtpro2 lite` version (I have seen the whole document). If we see the package `MnSymbol` (dots) to pag. 111 of the documentation The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, exists the `\squaredots` and we can built the symbol `\Coloneqq` with the macro `\mathrel{\mathop\squaredots}`:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}  
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{MnSymbol}
    \begin{document}
    $f(x)\mathrel{\mathop\squaredots}= \alpha^{\beta}_{\gamma}$
    \end{document}
```

`MnSymbol` differently from `txfonts`, keep the computer fonts modern (CM) but the distance between of the couple of the `:` and from `$f(x)$`. If I had to use this symbol with `mtpro2[lite]` package how I can built this symbol without to use `MnSymbol`, having the same symbol `\Coloneqq`  of `txfonts` that it is possible perfectly suited to `mtpro2[lite]` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the negative spacings to suit you.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cencolon}{{\mathop:}}

\newcommand{\Coloneqq}{%
  \mathrel{\cencolon}%
  \mspace{-2mu}%
  \mathrel{\cencolon}%
  \mspace{-2mu}%
  =%
}

\begin{document}

$f(x)\Coloneqq \alpha$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ...always...